# Configure Spring Boot application to use MongoDB connection uri provided in environment variable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I would like to configure the connection-uri to my MongoDB through an environment variable. This way, I can set different values on localhost or if the Spring Boot application is running in a cloud.

I have included mongodb in my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector:1.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    ...
}
```

To work locally, I have currently set the `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://...` in `applications.properties` but I would rather like to have that value read from an environment variable. How can I achieve this?

I have read articles about Spring Boot and Cloud suggesting extending the AbstractCloudConfig somehow like this:

```
public class CloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory documentMongoDbFactory() {
        return connectionFactory().mongoDbFactory();
    }

}
```

But I assume this wouldn't work with environment variables and working locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use profiles to do that.

[Read about profiles](http://www.ekiras.com/2016/06/springboot-what-are-profiles-in-spring.html)

[Read how to use Profiles](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/09/spring-how-to-get-current-profiles-in-spring-application.html)

[How to Set Profiles](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/11/how-to-set-active-profile-in-spring-boot-application.html)

Comment: Wonderful, thank you very much. I use `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev` locally and `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod` in the cloud. `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` both have `spring.data.mongodb.uri` declared but point to different instances. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again!